# Filtered Index in SQL Server missing predicate does not work as expected

Tags: sql-server, indexing, filtered-index

I am currently experimenting with filtered indexes in SQL Server. I was trying to shrink a filtered index down by putting the following hint from [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.100).aspx) into practice:

> A column in the filtered index expression does not need to be a key or
>   included column in the filtered index definition if the filtered index
>   expression is equivalent to the query predicate and the query does not
>   return the column in the filtered index expression with the query
>   results.

I have reproduced the problem in a small test script:
My table looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID  BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ARCHIVEDATE DATETIME NULL,
    CLOSINGDATE DATETIME NULL,
    OBJECTTYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ACTIVE BIT NOT NULL,
    FILLER1 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER2 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER3 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER4 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER5 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC)
);
```

I need to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(*) 
FROM    
    #test 
WHERE       
        ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL 
    AND CLOSINGDATE IS NOT NULL 
    AND ISNULL(ACTIVE,1) != 0
```

Therefore I have built the following filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_filterTest ON #test (/*ARCHIVEDATE ASC,*/CLOSINGDATE ASC) INCLUDE (ACTIVE) WHERE ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL;
```

ARCHIVEDATE is already in the filter and will not be used in SELECT thus it's not contained in the index keys or includes.

However, if I run the query I get the following plan:
[image: plan for query]
[image: filters for operators]

There's a key lookup in the clustered index for ARCHIVEDATE. Why is that so? I have reproduced this behaviour on SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2016.

If I create the index with ARCHIVEDATE in the key I get away with just an index seek. So it seems to me as this paragraph in BOL doesn't always apply.

Here's my complete repro script:

```
--DROP TABLE #test;
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID  BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ARCHIVEDATE DATETIME NULL,
    CLOSINGDATE DATETIME NULL,
    OBJECTTYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ACTIVE BIT NOT NULL,
    FILLER1 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER2 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER3 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER4 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    FILLER5 CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'just a filler',
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC)
);



INSERT INTO #test
(ARCHIVEDATE, CLOSINGDATE, OBJECTTYPE, ACTIVE)
SELECT TOP 200
    NULL,
    dates.calcDate,
    4711,
    dates.number%2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            /* Erzeugen des Datums durch Addieren der jeweiligen Sequenznummer zum StartDate */
            DATEADD(DAY, seq.number, '20120101') AS calcDate, number
        FROM
        (
            /* Abfrage zur Erstellung einer Nummernsequenz von 0 bis 9999. Dient als Basis zur Aufbereitung aller Datumswerte im Zeitraum. Die Sequenz reicht für einen Zeitraum von ca. 30 Jahren aus. */
            SELECT
                a.num * 1000 + b.num * 100 + c.num * 10 + d.num AS number
            FROM
                        ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
        ) seq 
        WHERE
            /* Einschränkung der Nummernsequenz auf die Anzahl der Tage im gewünschten Aufbereitungszeitraum */
            seq.number <= 5000
    ) dates
ORDER BY
    dates.number
;



INSERT INTO #test
(ARCHIVEDATE, CLOSINGDATE, OBJECTTYPE, ACTIVE)
SELECT TOP 1000
    dates.calcDate + 3,
    dates.calcDate,
    4711,
    dates.number%2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            /* Erzeugen des Datums durch Addieren der jeweiligen Sequenznummer zum StartDate */
            DATEADD(DAY, seq.number, '20120101') AS calcDate, number
        FROM
        (
            /* Abfrage zur Erstellung einer Nummernsequenz von 0 bis 9999. Dient als Basis zur Aufbereitung aller Datumswerte im Zeitraum. Die Sequenz reicht für einen Zeitraum von ca. 30 Jahren aus. */
            SELECT
                a.num * 1000 + b.num * 100 + c.num * 10 + d.num AS number
            FROM
                        ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
        ) seq 
        WHERE
            /* Einschränkung der Nummernsequenz auf die Anzahl der Tage im gewünschten Aufbereitungszeitraum */
            seq.number <= 5000
    ) dates
ORDER BY
    dates.number
;


INSERT INTO #test
(ARCHIVEDATE, CLOSINGDATE, OBJECTTYPE, ACTIVE)
SELECT TOP 100000
    dates.calcDate,
    NULL,
    4711,
    dates.number%2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            /* Erzeugen des Datums durch Addieren der jeweiligen Sequenznummer zum StartDate */
            DATEADD(DAY, seq.number, '20120101') AS calcDate, number
        FROM
        (
            /* Abfrage zur Erstellung einer Nummernsequenz von 0 bis 9999. Dient als Basis zur Aufbereitung aller Datumswerte im Zeitraum. Die Sequenz reicht für einen Zeitraum von ca. 30 Jahren aus. */
            SELECT
                a.num * 1000 + b.num * 100 + c.num * 10 + d.num AS number
            FROM
                        ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
            CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
        ) seq 
        WHERE
            /* Einschränkung der Nummernsequenz auf die Anzahl der Tage im gewünschten Aufbereitungszeitraum */
            seq.number <= 5000
    ) dates
ORDER BY
    dates.number
;


--DROP INDEX idx_filterTest ON #test;
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_filterTest ON #test (ARCHIVEDATE ASC,CLOSINGDATE ASC) INCLUDE (ACTIVE) WHERE ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_filterTest ON #test (/*ARCHIVEDATE ASC,*/CLOSINGDATE ASC) INCLUDE (ACTIVE) WHERE ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL;



SELECT  
    COUNT(*) 
FROM    
    #test 
WHERE       
        ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL 
    AND CLOSINGDATE IS NOT NULL 
    AND ISNULL(ACTIVE,1) != 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the optimizer, specifically in the way it handles `IS NULL` filters. Here's a simpler repro:

```
CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, X INT);
INSERT #T(X) SELECT TOP(10000) message_id FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id <> 1;
INSERT #T(X) VALUES (1);
INSERT #T(X) VALUES (NULL);
CREATE INDEX IX_#T_X_null ON #T(ID) WHERE X IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX IX_#T_X_1 ON #T(ID) WHERE X = 1;
```

Clearly the following query is covered by `IX_#T_X_null`:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #T WHERE X IS NULL;
```

And the optimizer indeed picks it, but we get an execution plan where a superfluous clustered index lookup is inserted. But:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #T WHERE X = 1;
```

Now we get a query without a clustered index lookup. When `IS NULL` is involved, the optimizer seems to recognize that the filtered index applies, but is then unable to propagate the condition to a later step. We can clearly see this if we include the column with the index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_#T_X_null ON #T(ID, X) WHERE X IS NULL;
```

If you now compare the execution plans of the `WHERE X = 1` and `WHERE X IS NULL` queries, you'll see that in the case of `X IS NULL`, the optimizer adds a predicate into the index scan, which it doesn't do with `X = 1`.

And delving into a bit a bit further, with this specific setup, you can find this is a [known issue, already reported on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/454744/filtered-index-not-used-and-key-lookup-with-no-output). According to Microsoft, however, "this is actually not a bug but rather a known gap in functionality" (which I suppose is technically true, since the results are not incorrect, it just doesn't perform as well as it could). Also, "this is now an active DCR for a future release of SQL Server", but that was 6 years ago, and the ticket is closed as "Won't Fix" -- so don't hold your breath.

Unfortunately, the workaround is indeed to include the column in the index -- I'd make it an included column and not a key, since that adds overhead to the non-leaf levels:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_filterTest ON #test (CLOSINGDATE ASC)
INCLUDE (ACTIVE, ARCHIVEDATE) 
WHERE ARCHIVEDATE IS NULL;
```

I say "unfortunately" because this always-`NULL` column will still pointlessly take up row space (since `DATETIME` is a fixed size data type). Even so, it's probably miles better than getting extra I/O from clustered index lookups. Also, the overhead can be reduced to almost nothing by [compressing the index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc280449) (even row compression will do).

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for the very helpful answer. Now I know, that I haven't done something wrong. You're right...including the column is a better option to go as the filter condition narrows down the values to just NULL and I won't get any better seeks by indexing on it.